# kafka-consumer-groups command issue

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I run this command:

> kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group my-consumer-group --reset-offsets --to-earliest --execute --topic my-topic-1

It gives error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

As per the help results for this command, what I have typed seems to be right.

What mistake am I making here?

Comment: Could you try with the - - execute at the end of the command line? What version of Kafka binary you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: `--execute` does not seems to be required as per the [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_consumer_group) example when resetting offset for a consumer group.

EDIT2: I have looked into the [source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.3.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala#L385), apparently `--execute` is needed else it would be treated as a dry run thus offset will not be reset. If your binary is built before this [fix](https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/e26d0d760466c3da6189637a7de69eb5509e7b51#diff-f1b330624af520e6f9824bd308e21f24), then you will get the mentioned invalid command error.

---

Remove it and your command will work:

`kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group my-consumer-group --reset-offsets --to-earliest --topic my-topic-1`

Comment: You should link to some particular version (tag). As per documentation option `--execute` it is required to `to execute --reset-offsets process.`

Comment: Yes, `--execute` is required in order to reset offsets else it would be considered as a dry run as I mentioned above. This is applicable to all Kafka version that supports `-reset-offsets` flag.